# BeautifulSoup indexes

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup

so I am trying to parse the links for the genres and subgenres in the IMDB page http://www.imdb.com/genre/?ref_=nv_ch_gr_3

and have now been able to parse the main genre tags into something usable
with the following code

```
table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "genre-table"})

for item in table:
    for x in range(100):

        try:
            print(item.contents[x].find_all("h3"))
            print(len(item.contents[x].find_all("h3")))
        except:
            pass
```

and my output is 11 sets of lists with two tags in it like this

```
[<h3><a href="http://www.imdb.com/genre/action/?ref_=gnr_mn_ac_mp">Action <span class="normal">»</span></a></h3>, <h3><a href="http://www.imdb.com/genre/adventure/?ref_=gnr_mn_ad_mp">Adventure <span class="normal">»</span></a></h3>]
2
```

I understand this because the containers have a class of "even" and "odd" with two h3 tags in each container, but I didnt specify it to differentiate between even and odd, actually I think I am answering my own question here, am I right in thinking that because it was in a container class odd or even, that bs4 put it in a list to just show that and its up to me to separate them?

Second more important question:

how would I get each h3 link  and title into my dataframe that I have set up as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Genre', 'Sub-Genre', 'Link'])
```

I've tried

for y in range(2):

```
df.append({'Genre':'item.contents[x].find_all("h3"))[y].text)},     ignore_index = true)
```

This is nested in the for loop with x of course (not on its own)
but it doesnt seem to work 
any thoughts? karma your way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off there's no need to find all tables since only the first one is neccessary:

```
table = soup.find("table", {'class': 'genre-table'})
```

and since every other item is redundant(starting with the first) you can iterate the table like this:

```
for item in list(table)[1::2]:
```

after this we can get the 'h3' tags in every row and loop through both of them:

```
    row = item.find_all("h3")

    for col in row:
```

because the text in every 'h3' element returns the genre in this format: 'Somegenre \xc2\xbb' i removed the span element before getting the the text:

```
        col.span.extract()
        link = col.a['href']
        genre = col.text.strip()
```

after this just add the elements in to a dataframe by index:

```
        df.loc[len(df)]=[genre, None, link]
```

full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Genre', 'Sub-Genre', 'Link'])

req = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/genre/?ref_=nv_ch_gr_3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", {'class': 'genre-table'})

for item in list(table)[1::2]:
    row = item.find_all("h3")

    for col in row:
        col.span.extract()
        link = col.a['href']
        genre = col.text.strip()

        df.loc[len(df)] = [genre, None, link]
```

Comment: man that is perfect sorted me right out, got to go and study up on some of these functions haha, one question though, when you sliced the list how are you iterating over it? Im slightly thrown by the two colons

Comment: EDIT i just dont understand how you have sliced on 4 positions as in 4 elements in the list(table)[elements-go-here]

Comment: @entercaspa im not sure what you mean but the list(table) returns a list of the table elements so that i could slice them. The syntax works like this: [start:end] or [start:end:step]. start defaults to 0 and end defaults to len(list) so you can leave them out like this: [start:], [:end] or [:]. the last option step allows you to step over elements and here [1:(end):2] we are skipping every second element. The syntax [::3] would skip every third and so on.

Comment: yeah know that makes sense sorry Im new to this and almost forgot how slicing worked, haha thanks man youve been such a help